# How to change a parent view by clicking a button inside of subview in swift (Xcode)

Tags: ios, swift, button, xib, subview

I am working on an app which needs a menu bar, it should be used in many different views, so here is what i did.

**I make a subview which is the menu, it is loaded by other view in Main.storyboard.**

1. Main.storyboard       ----- this contains parent view
2. SimpleCustomView.xib  ----- this is the subview

**Here is the Problem:**

- How can I make a button inside of `SimpleCustomView` which can change the parent view in Main.storyboard? So the users can click on the menu to switch pages.

**I have tried:**

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PC") as UIViewController

// self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

//superview.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**Neither 3rd line nor 4th line works.**

So i got quite confused, how can i do it.

Comment: Please do not post code as an image. Please [edit] your question and copy and paste your actual code into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general approach in a situation such as yours, where you want multiple views to show a certain view from a parent view, would be to send a notification from the child view when the button is clicked. The parent view would be listening for that particular message and then carry out an action - show the menu in this case.

Since I don't know enough about your particular set up, I don't want to hazard providing code which might not really work for you :) If you are able to share your project with us, then I can take a look and give you specific code which should work.